# Formatting curriculum vitae in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, margins, cv

I am trying to create my curriculum vitae within LaTeX. I have tried working with templates, but that did not lead to the desired result.

I have created, in my opinion, a very clean cv within Microsoft Word, but the conversion to PDF spoils it. Therefore, my aim is to replicate the document within LaTeX.

I am struggling to get the margins and columns straight that allows me to implement all the cv details.

Please find attached an example of the format I am trying to achieve.

[image: cv1]

[image: cv2]

Comment: Converting the Word file to LaTeX via [`pandoc`](https://pandoc.org/) may give you a good starting point for the TeX code

Comment: Unfortunately, thus far pandoc has done a poor job at providing a starting point, it basically has only copied the text and did very little for the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

For example can you use the class `moderncv`, style `banking`.  The only difference I see is the position of personal datas:

[image]

resulting after compiling this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % \rmdefault
%\nopagenumbers{} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
%\settowidth{\hintscolumnwidth}{Jun-Sep, 2011} 
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % for the 'classic' style

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description 
  no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description 
  line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore 
  normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation 
  when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

\end{document}
```

If you want to change the color `blue` to `black` use the line

```
\moderncvcolor{black}
```

Let me add a remark to your sentence:

> I am struggling to get the margins and columns straight that allows me
>   to implement all the cv details.

For me that sounds that you should rework the content of your cv to be minimal needed. Often people adds informations not needed for the current job you write the cv for. I know that is not easy to do, but it is neccessary to get a good cv.

Are you sure you need the date of birth and place on your cv?

For example you can use:

```
\section{Personal Data}
\cvitem{Driving license}{B}
\cvitem{Nationality}{German}
\cvitem{Date and place of birth}{date, place}
```

Comment: Thanks. the education part is somewhat extensive, but at this point it is my main selling point. The curriculum does need some explanation, as different people have different compositions of courses within that same program.